# How To Get Unselected Option Value In Bootstrap davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect dro down list

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect drop down list and I want to get unselected value(s) when I get a drop down list:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Course" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Dashbord *</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="multicourse">
        <select id="Course" name="options[]" multiple="multiple"  style="width:100%">

            <option value="1"  >Sales</option>
            <option value="2" >Students</option>
            <option value="3" >Quetion</option>
            <option value="4" >Test</option>
            <option value="5" >Test Series</option>
            <option value="6" >Student</option>
            <option value="7" >Validity</option>
            <option value="8" >Disk Space</option>
            <option value="9" >Student Graph</option>
            <option value="10"  >Date</option>

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the script:

```
$('#Course').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    nonSelectedText:"Select Dashbord",
    nSelectedText:"Dashbord",
    enableFiltering: true,
    maxHeight:200,
    buttonWidth: '95%',
});
$("#Course").multiselect('selectAll', false);
$("#Course").multiselect('updateButtonText');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand your questions, but here are some proposals. You can get the values of all selected options as follows:

```
$('#Course option:selected')
```

Similarly you can get all unselected options:

```
$('#Course option:not(:selected)')
```

The corresponding input elements can be queried as follows. I am assuming the you use `buttonContainer: '<div id="multiselect-container"></div>'` as option for simplicity:

```
// Alternatively use `:not(:selected)` as above:
var value = $('#Course option:selected')[0].val()
$input = $('#multiselect-container input[value="# + value + '"]') // The checkbox
$input.prop('checked`) // Whether it is checked (its checked when the correspondign option is selected)
$input.closest('li') // Corresponding list item
// ...
```